# Why python executable file's icon disappear when it is out from the 'dist folder?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I recently created a python executable file with an icon by using the command,

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=logo.ico program.py
```

It was created successfully with the icon. When I took out the executable from the 'dist' folder, the icon was reset with the default pyinstaller executable icon. Is there any solution for me :-)

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you could assign your own icon. With the onefile option, how many files are in the 'dist' folder? Just the exe file? I wonder if you have to make sure to attach the icon file in your distribution. Often you put extra files to attach inside a spec file. According to [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html), you use the command line switches `--add-data` or `add-binary` to add text or binary files, respectively.